# New to Java: Do While Loops and Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, do-while

I am attempting to write a program for an intro java class that takes in a wall's width and height, calculates the area and then outputs the amount of paint required for that wall. I have the code working just fine if the user were to input the correct values, but I'm having trouble with my try, throw, catch statements. They successfully throw and catch the errors, but I want it to prompt the user for another input if an error is found and my do while loop doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/************************************************************************
 * This program is designed to take the area and width of a user given 
 * wall and output number of gallons of paint required.
 * Written by: Nicholas Phelps
 * Date: August 4, 2021
 ************************************************************************/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paint1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        double wallHeight = 0.0;
        double wallWidth = 0.0;
        double wallArea = 0.0;
        double gallonsPaintNeeded = 0.0;
        
        final double squareFeetPerGallons = 350.0;
        
        
        /************************************************************************************
         * Created a do while loop that utilizes try, throw, catch statements for error
         * checking. If 'wallHeight' is less than 0.0 then the error message will print and 
         * continues until a valid entry has been made.
         ***********************************************************************************/
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
            try {
                //Get user data
                wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
                
                //Error checking, non-negative height
                if(wallHeight < 0.0) {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid height.");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception excpt) {
                //Prints error message
                System.out.println(excpt.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Cannont calculate required paint. Please try again.");
            }
        }
        while(wallHeight < 0.0);
        

        /***********************************************************************************
         * Correction was made here. 'wallHeight' was used twice, changed to 'wallWidth'.
         * Created a do while loop that utilizes try, throw, catch statements for error 
         * checking. If 'wallWidth' is less than 0.0, then the error message will print and
         * loop continues until valid value has been entered. 
         ***********************************************************************************/
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter wall width (feet): ");
            try {
                //Get user data
                wallWidth = scnr.nextDouble();
                
                //Error checking, non-negative width
                if(wallWidth < 0.0) {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid width.");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception excpt) {
                //Prints error message
                System.out.println(excpt.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Cannont calculate required paint. Please try again.");
            }
        }
        while(wallWidth < 0.0);
        

        // Calculate and output wall area
        wallArea = wallHeight * wallWidth;
        System.out.println("Wall area: " + wallArea + " square feet");                      //Correction made: 'wallArea' missing from print statement, 'wallArea' added

        // Calculate and output the amount of paint (in gallons) needed to paint the wall
        gallonsPaintNeeded = wallArea/squareFeetPerGallons;
        System.out.println("Paint needed: " + gallonsPaintNeeded + " gallons");             //Correction made: 'gallonspaintneeded' updated to 'gallonsPaintNeeded"

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas, and best of luck on your project.  I'm a little confused as it appears that your app behaves exactly as you want it to.  It asks for the height and if it gets a value less than 0 it throws an exception which is caught, a message is sent indicating the error and then it asks again for the height.

Comment: Exactly what messages are you seeing?

Comment: I tried to execute this and i am getting the following output.It seems to be correct..can you please pinpoint what is the problem..Enter wall height (feet): 
-21
Invalid height.
Can not calculate required paint. Please try again.
Cannont calculate required paint. Please try again.
Enter wall height (feet): 
21
Cannont calculate required paint. Please try again.
Enter wall width (feet): 
-23.00
Invalid width.
Cannont calculate required paint. Please try again.
Enter wall width (feet): 
23
Wall area: 483.0 square feet
Paint needed: 1.38 gallons

Comment: So it may be the IDE that I’m using for school, but the issue I’m having is when I enter a string instead of an integer. The program catches the exception and returns values as null, but doesn’t loop back. Again, it may just be the IDE I’m using or maybe I need to check for both incorrect integers and literals? This is what populates on the eclipse built in console:      Enter wall height (feet): thirty null Cannot calculate required paint. Please try again. Enter wall width (feet): null Cannot calculate required paint. Please try again. Wall Area: 0.0 square feet Paint needed: 0.0 gallons

Comment: After `nextDouble` has thrown an exception, what value will `wallWidth` have? Will that value make your loop continue, or exit? You can step through your program with the debugger if you aren't sure.